# Books from Esri Press

Tags: esri-company, references

Which books from [Esri Press](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?CFID=7918674&CFTOKEN=49838228) can you recommend?

Answer (score 8):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

- Getting to Know ArcGIS Desktop: for learning the BASICS of GIS
- Designing Geodatabases: Case Studies in GIS Data Modeling :This book provides a good introduction of steps and principles in designing geodatabases
- A to Z GIS: An Illustrated Dictionary of Geographic Information Systems: AN ILLUSTRATED DICTIONARY OF GEOGEPHIC INFORMATION SYSTEMS.
- The ESRI Guide to GIS Analysis Volume 1: Geographic Patterns & Relationships
- The ESRI Guide to GIS Analysis: Volume 2: Spatial Measurements and Statistics
  :An extremely basic, starting point for any would-be GIS Analyst
- [Designing Better Maps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589480899) is great resource, even if you don't use ESRI products.
- [Modeling Our World](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1879102625) was helpful for me as well, especially at the begining of my adventure with GIS. It seems this book has been [updated](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589482786), however I haven't had a chance to see 2nd edition.
- [Getting to Know ArcObjects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158948018X) An awesome book that I still reference regularly.  Need something of a similar standard, but updated around .NET instead of VBA. (VBA is being deprecated)
- [Lining Up Data in ArcGIS: A Guide to Map](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=171&moduleID=0)  and your going to need to know about projections.
- [Semiology of Graphics: Diagrams, Networks, Maps](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=190&moduleID=0) is excellent, and is the most popular non-GIS book published by ESRI.
- [GIS for Decision Support and Public Policy Making](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158948231X) is a must-read for anyone interested in GIS for local governments.  The authors go over specific case studies for 27 jurisdictions and shows the specific ROI they experienced from their GIS projects.
- [Fun with GPS](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=91): on the lighter side, it has lots of ideas for doing GPS with kids (and kid-minded adults)
- [Python Scripting for ArcGIS](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteid=276&moduleid=0): Python Scripting for ArcGIS is a guide for experienced users of ArcGIS Desktop to get started with Python scripting without needing previous programming experience.