# Map Projection - where to begin

Tags: coordinate-system

First of all, I realize that this question can be considered like "open" or maybe "too wide" (and definitely very basic for all of you). However, I am completely new in this and I am not looking for more then several hits where to begin, which topics I should search for.

Also, I search for some similar questions and I found few open questions with similar meaning ([Java, GIS knowledge…What next?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4204/java-gis-knowledge-what-next), [The Best books from ESRI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3655/the-best-books-from-esri/3667#3667), [Where can I find QGIS tutorials and resources?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/where-can-i-find-qgis-tutorials-and-resources/3657#3657)) so I hope someone can help.

**The Issues:**

---

I have data in geographical coordinates which I would like to project them into geomagnetic coordinates.

---

What do I need for that? Is information on the internet enough to solve this or I should search for a book? What should I search for?

Comment: Please check out few links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948450/conversion-from-geographic-to-geomagnetic-coordinates

Comment: +1 http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29157/how-can-i-convert-geomagnetic-coordinates

Comment: @Sunil ok, thank you, that just made my life much easier :)